# Converting to a portable file path

Tags: java, regex, exception

```
public static String getPortableFilePath(String target)    
{
Pattern ptr=Pattern.compile("[\\|/]+");
Matcher mtr=ptr.matcher(target);
return mtr.replaceAll(File.separator);  
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   System.out.println(getPortableFilePath("C:///Program Files////Java\\jdk1.6.0_23/bin"));  
}
```

In the above code I am trying to replace all the Forward and Backward slashes with the current systems File Separator. Code compiles fine when put into a class, but when executed it gives an array index out of bounds exception. Any guesses why?

The Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1

at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
at Files.getPortableFilePath
at Files.main
```

Comment: I just built and run your snippet JavaSE-1.6 on Mac 10.6.7 and it worked perfectly. I didn't get the error you describe.

Comment: That looks like an internal bug in regex.Matcher. Seems like it was fixed in newer Java versions. If you keep hitting it you can try doing a manual replace. Since paths aren't going to be too long you can even just iterate character by character.

Comment: Why are you matching a literal pipe?

Comment: @Adam: It is not a bug in Java.  It is a bug in the user-specified regex.

Comment: Ok, i thought the pipe symbol will work as an OR operator, rather it's working as a literal.

Comment: @tchrist, the bug in the regex should just yield incorrect results, not raise an out of bounds exception inside the system call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get two backslashes through to the regex engine.  Otherwise it will think you are escaping the next character.  So use

```
"[\\\\/]+"
```

for the pattern string.  That way it resolves to the pattern

```
[\\/]+
```

This is the problem with the string and the regex notation both using backslashes, and there being no way to skip the string interpolation stage.

And don’t use a vertical pipe in a square-bracket charclass: it is a literal there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer tchrist.I updated the code as per your comments, this was actually needed for the code to work properly. But it didn't fix the actual error, please see my answer below for the actual fix.

Answer (score 3):

You method is (a) misnamed and (b) unnecessary. Misnamed because it doesn't return a portable file path, it returns a path for the current system; unnecessary because if you just use / everywhere Java will operate correctly on all platforms. There is never a need to use backslashes in Java filenames.

Comment: Yeah that's perfectly fine, i was just trying to implement this functionality myself, but found this strange error so asked.

Comment: @Lavneesh But there is no functionality to implement ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answers guys. Finally found the issue.

I replaced the

```
Pattern ptr=Pattern.compile("[\\\\/]+");
```

with

```
Pattern ptr=Pattern.compile("[\\\\\\\\|/]+");
```

as noted by tchrist, this was needed but still it didn't fix the error.

The error was fixed by replacing the

```
return mtr.replaceAll(File.separator);
```

line with

```
return mtr.replaceAll(File.separator+""+File.separator);
```

Since I am working in windows environment, the `File.separator` returned "\" which itself worked as an escape character and the error was displayed, and that is why the original code worked fine on Jim Blackler's Mac because the `File.separator` for him was not "\".

But still I could not make sense with the `StringIndexoutOfBounds` exception, what does this exception had to do here.

Comment: This is just further compounding the original error, which is that you don't need to do any of this. You have just written non-portable code for something that was already portable before you started.